# unable to create react app : terminal gets stuck whenever i run command

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

whenever i run command `npm init react-app my-app` my terminal gets stuck here

> PS C:\Users\USER> npm install -g create-react-app
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app ->
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
>
> - create-react-app@3.4.1 added 98 packages from 46 contributors in 136.484s PS C:\Users\USER> npm init react-app my-app
>
> Creating a new React app in C:\Users\USER\my-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

and nothing happens after this..

when i ran command `npm init react-app my-app --verbose` the terminal got stuck here:

> PS C:\Users\USER> cd desktop  PS C:\Users\USER\desktop> npm init
> react-app my-app --verbose npm info it worked if it ends with ok npm
> verb cli [ npm verb cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe', npm
> verb cli
> 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
> npm verb cli   'init',      npm verb cli   'react-app', npm verb cli
> 'my-app',    npm verb cli   '--verbose'  npm verb cli ] npm info using
> npm@6.14.8   npm info using node@v12.18.3 [..................] - :
> info using node@v12.18.3 Creating a new React app in
> C:\Users\USER\desktop\my-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> [..................] - : info using node@v12.18.3

**nothing happened after this, waited for more 2 hours..**

**i have tried literally everything like: using `npx creat-react-app my-app` command after uninstalling create-react-app global package, updated node and npm to the latest versions, reinstalled node 3 times and so on.**

**it's been months that i'm stuck here and not be able to create my app. PLEASE, ANYONE, HELP. PLEASE..**

Comment: Please include all text-based information as text rather than pictures of text. This includes console messages and the contents of files.

Comment: Can you run `npm init react-app my-app1 --verbose`? That way you get a lot more information. I suspect that you are just not patient enough for all the packages to install.

Comment: It is not appropriate to notify users, especially more than once, asking for help. If I knew what the problem was, I'd answer the question. In this case, I commented because I knew that images of error text do not help people with vision problems, nor search engines, understand the problem. This sounds like an issue where reinstalling the OS would be the next step.

Comment: Apologies, i didn't knew this.